# Query a string column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column, call 'expected_salary'. By the name, it suppose to be some numerical value. But I would like it to also hold value such as "competitive", "commission based" etc, so, it became a string type.

Now the dumb problem is, I would like to query it, like, `SELECT all rows where expected_salary >= 3000`. Of course, it won't work with a normal numeric comparison.

Before I convert the 'expected_salary' to integer type, and created an extra column call 'other_salary', I would like to know, if there is better solution.

Comment: `SELECT all rows where expected_salary::numeric >= 3000` ?? if possible provide sample table and data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, create additional columns, probably booleans, which are false by default.  `is_commissioned`, `is_competitive`, etc.

Then the proper query is

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE expected_salary >= 3000 AND is_competitive
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have the delimited value.

For example:

for expected_salary=`'3000, salary comments'`.

You can try below query.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE CAST(SUBSTRING(expected_salary, 0, PATINDEX('%,%',expected_salary)) as INT) >= 3000
```

Answer (score 0):

A guess:

```
create table salaries ( 
    expected_salary text
    );

insert into salaries values ('1000'),('1500,comment'),('3000,comment'),('3500'),
                                        ('comment'),('4000'),('4500,comment');
```

you can use `substring()` function to extract `Integer` from a `string`

```
select * from (
select substring(expected_salary FROM '[0-9]+')::int sal from salaries
) t where sal >=3000;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the where add "and expected_salary not in" with the values that can't be compared to numbers.